# Can we pass JSON format to read the docs?

Tags: json, html-table, read-the-docs

is there a way to pass JSON to read the docs and it can read and generate a html page with table structure or something of similar sorts?

E.g.

```
{
    "math": [
        {
            "Type": "A",
            "description": "Create A",
            "tags": [
                "math",
                "alpha",
            ],
            "method": "Create"
        },
        {
            "returnType": "B",
            "description": "Multiply",
            "tags": [
                "math"
            ],
            "method": "Mult"
        }
    ]
}
```

output: an html table view. something like this
[image]

Comment: could you give us an example about your input and the expected output?

Comment: @MayraNavarro i have edited the question for more clarification